# Can not activate sandbox after refreshing sandbox

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

yesterday I tried to refresh sandbox in orgs
And now It indicates that ready to `activate` the sandbox
[image]

but when I tried to use `sf data update record` with below full command

```
sf data update record --json --use-tooling-api --target-org $targetOrgAlias \
      --sobject SandboxInfo --record-id $sandboxInfoId \
      --values "RefreshAction=ACTIVATE" --values "LicenseType=$licenseType"
```

It prompts below error

```
The sandbox you tried to refresh or delete has a current status of ACTIVATION_PENDING_CONFIRM. Wait until its status is Finished, and then try again.
```

[image]
so Im wondering which field I should update to activate sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found issue by myself, It should update`RefreshAction=ACTIVATE` in sobject`SandboxProcess` instead

```
sf data update record --json --use-tooling-api --target-org $targetOrgAlias \
      --sobject SandboxProcess --record-id $sandboxProgressId \
      --values "RefreshAction=ACTIVATE"
```